# button div not clickable only work if I click on text tried everything nothing works

Tags: html, css

I try to create hover animation button but I don't know why it's not working when I click on div only works if I click on their text even I write `display:block` in anchor tag.
Below is my html and css code also jsfiddle.

Html :

```
<div class="animation-button">
  <div class="raised hoverable">
    <div class="anim"></div><span><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=about&Itemid=104">More About Us</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Css :

```
.animation-button .raised {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
  padding: 10px 19px;
  text-align: center;
  //min-width:14%;
  /*width: 200px;*/
  /*border-radius: 5px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}
.animation-button .raised {
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  background: #849C8E;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #849C8E;
}
.animation-button .raised:active {
  background: #70897A;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #70897A;
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

.animation-button .raised span a {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.animation-button span a:hover,#ankur span a:focus{
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}

.anim {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}
.anim:before {
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}
.anim:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hoverable:hover > .anim {
  -moz-animation: anim-out 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation: anim-out 0.75s;
  animation: anim-out 0.75s;
}
.hoverable:hover > .anim:after {
  -moz-animation: anim-out-pseudo 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation: anim-out-pseudo 0.75s;
  animation: anim-out-pseudo 0.75s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@-ms-keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
@keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/a2zgk/yL8ngrx5/1/

Comment: and whats not working??

Comment: i want if someone click on div it also click like a normal link.

Comment: The problem is clicking outsite the text (but still inside the button) will not open a new page.

Comment: @AnkurDubey simply wrap the div itself not just the text in the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the padding to the `a` tag instead of the `button` so that the link cover the whole area of the button like this :

```css
.animation-button .raised {
  position: relative;
  margin: 1em;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  //min-width:14%;
  /*width: 200px;*/
  /*border-radius: 5px;*/
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
}

.animation-button .raised {
  -moz-transition: all 0.1s;
  -o-transition: all 0.1s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.1s;
  transition: all 0.1s;
  background: #849C8E;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #849C8E;
}

.animation-button .raised:active {
  background: #70897A;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #70897A;
  /* display: inline-block; */
}

.animation-button .raised span a {
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 3vw;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 19px;
}

.animation-button span a:hover,
#ankur span a:focus {
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}

.anim {
  -moz-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%) translateX(-50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.anim:before {
  position: relative;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  margin-top: 100%;
}

.anim:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.hoverable:hover>.anim {
  -moz-animation: anim-out 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation: anim-out 0.75s;
  animation: anim-out 0.75s;
}

.hoverable:hover>.anim:after {
  -moz-animation: anim-out-pseudo 0.75s;
  -webkit-animation: anim-out-pseudo 0.75s;
  animation: anim-out-pseudo 0.75s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-in {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-in-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-out {
  0% {
    width: 0%;
  }
  100% {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@-ms-keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}

@keyframes anim-out-pseudo {
  0% {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
  }
  100% {
    background: transparent;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="animation-button">
  <div class="raised hoverable">
    <div class="anim"></div><span><a href="index.php?option=com_content&view=about&Itemid=104">More About Us</a></span>
  </div>
</div>
```